# DataSource appears to be working but tableView is not reloading

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, datasource

I've got an issue where my `tableView` isn't updating based on the datasource correctly. I'm using a tabbed application structure with Storyboards.

My overall goal here is to have a `tableView` on the second tab display items that are removed from an array stored in a struct. The items are added to the array from the first tab.

There are 2 `ViewControllers` (1 for the interface for scrolling through items and selecting to remove them, and 1 to handle the tableView) and 2 Views (1 for the interface for scrolling through items and removing them and 1 for the tableView). The first tab is for providing the interface for removing the items and the second tab is for the `tableView`.

The remove and add to the array functionality works, just not the displaying it in the `tableView`.

Currently, if I hard code items in my **"removed items"** array, they are displayed in the `tableView`. The problem is that as I add items to the array from my `removeItem` function in the first `ViewController`, the `tableView` does not update, only the hard coded items are shown.

This makes me assume that I have my datasource and delegate setup correctly, since the `tableView` is getting it's data from the intended datasource. The issue is it's not updating as the user updates the array with new items.

I've tried using `self.tableView.reloadData()` with no success. I might not be calling in the correct location though.

I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

Here is my second view controller that controls the tableView

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"

var removedTopicsFromList = containerForRemovedTopics()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// UITableViewDataSource methods

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return removedTopicsFromList.removedTopics.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.removedTopicsFromList.removedTopics[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Here is the struct where the removed phrases are stored

```
struct containerForRemovedTopics {

var removedTopics: [String] = []

}
```

Answer (score 0):

structure instances are always passed by value. So if your code is something like:

```
var removedTopicsFromList = secondViewController.removedTopicsFromList
removedTopicsFromList.removedTopics.append("SomeTopic")
secondViewController.reloadData()
```

then you are changing the different structure.

Maybe you got stuck with this problem I guess.

Comment: Not sure that's the issue. The datasource appears correct, the tableView just won't update after the datasource has been updated. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: Would you like to show how you set the tableview's data source in the first view controller?